# Does $L[0,\pi]$ have an uncountable basis of phase-shifted sinusoids?

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Typically the space $L[0,\pi]$ is said to have a orthogonal basis that consists of the harmonics of sine and cosine, i.e. $\{1,\sin(n\omega t),\cos(n\omega t)\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

However you can also think of the Fourier spectrum of a signal in terms of frequency and phase rather than sines and cosines. Does that mean that there is an uncountable (non-orthogonal) basis that consists of $\{1,\sin(n\omega t-\phi)\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}, \phi\in[0,\pi]\}$?

Does it even make sense to think about uncountable bases? Or does it open some kinda can of worms?

Comment: In any case, the set you've given is not a basis.  Any two values of $\phi \in [0,\pi)$ correspond to a basis, but if you use all of them, there's a lot of linear dependence going on. (remember $\sin(a+b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b)$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see. I guess if I wanted to stick with a single function (for instance $\sin$), the equivalence would be $\sin(t-\phi)=\sin(\phi-\pi/2)\sin(t)+\sin(\phi)\sin(t-\pi/2)$, i.e. a linear combination of $\sin(t)$ and $\sin(t-\pi/2)$. I guess my question then is that it's so natural to think about signals in terms of frequency and phase and yet it appears that mathematically we only ever need two phases. Is there some underlying reason why this intuitive view of signals has so much redundancy?

Comment: To explain my confusion a bit more, it seems that waves intuitively have 3 degrees of freedom: amplitude, frequency, and phase. However, phase apparently isn't a full degree of freedom; it only needs to take on two different values (or rather it doesn't even exist if you think of $\cos$ as its own thing). Phase appears to be some kind of pseudo-property. Although I guess amplitude is also a kind of pseudo-property in that $2\sin(t)$ is just $\sin(t)+\sin(t)$. Frequency seems to be the only fundamental property.

Comment: You should keep in mind that orthogonal basis of trigonometric functions is *not* a basis in the sense of linear algebra, because typical vectors in $L^2$ can't be written as *finite* linear combinations of sines and cosines. On the other hand, every vector is a limit of such finite linear combinations (consider trumcations of Fourier series to first N terms, let N go to infinity). Using Zorn's lemma one can show that bases in purely algebraic sense also exist, but you will be hard pressed to actually construct one.

Comment: Also, every two orthogonal bases have the same number of elements (countable infinity for the Hilbert space $L^2$. Similarly, every two algebraic based have the same number (cardinality) of elements. But the latter cardinality is strictly larger (not countable).

Comment: I see so despite the rules of traditional linear algebra not applying, the idea that a basis is the largest spanning set (and thus any set of vectors larger than that must be linearly dependent) still holds. I can see why everything is working out mathematically but there's still a gap in my brain philosophically :(

Comment: Have you studied basic Hilbert space theory? I recommend it.

Comment: I tried reading the Wikipedia and got confused really quickly. Even the Wikipedia for Lebesgue spaces gets out of hand super fast...